# Login C# conectado a Oracle con 3 niveles de usuarios

Tags: visual-studio, oracle

Bueno, contarles que estoy realizando un sistema y necesito visualizar 3 tipos de usuarios:

Administrador
Vendedor
Empleado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo con el que estoy trabajando es el siguiente:

```
        {
            this.cnn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd;
            OracleDataReader reg;
            string con = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '" + u + "' AND contrasena ='" + c + "' AND ID_USUARIO= 01  ";
            cmd = new OracleCommand(con, cnn);
            reg = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reg.Read();
            if (reg.HasRows)
            {
                nombre = reg["NOMBRE_USUARIO"].ToString();
                tipo = "1";
                rut = reg["RUT_USUARIO"].ToString();
                cnn.Close();
                return true;
            }
                else
                {
                    string vend = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '" + u + "' AND contrasena ='" + c + "' AND ID_USUARIO= 02 ";
                    cmd = new OracleCommand(vend, cnn);
                    reg = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reg.Read();
                    if (reg.HasRows)
                    {
                        nombre = reg["NOMBRE_USUARIO"].ToString();
                        tipo = "2";
                        rut = reg["RUT_USUARIO"].ToString();
                        cnn.Close();
                        return true;
                    }
                else
                {
                    string emp = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '" + u + "' AND contrasena ='" + c + "' AND ID_USUARIO= 03 ";
                    cmd = new OracleCommand(emp, cnn);
                    reg = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reg.Read();
                    if (reg.HasRows)
                    {
                        nombre = reg["NOMBRE_USUARIO"].ToString();
                        tipo = "3";
                        rut = reg["RUT_USUARIO"].ToString();
                        cnn.Close();
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                    {

                        cnn.Close();
                        return false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Este mismo, me define un usuario asignandole un tipo (1,2,3) para poder perfilar con este validador:

```
        {
            Login UsuarioOB = new Login();
            UsuarioOB.Usuario = textBox1.Text;
            UsuarioOB.Constrasena = textBox2.Text;
            if (UsuarioOB.ValidarLogin(UsuarioOB.Usuario, UsuarioOB.Constrasena))
            {

                if (UsuarioOB.Tipo == "nulo")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("usuario no activo ");


                }

                else
                {
                    if (UsuarioOB.Tipo == "1")
                    {
                        LoginAdmin adm = new LoginAdmin(UsuarioOB.Nombre, UsuarioOB.Rut);
                        adm.Show();
                        this.Hide();

                    }
                    else if(UsuarioOB.Tipo == "2")
                    {
                        LoginVendedor vend = new LoginVendedor(UsuarioOB.Nombre, UsuarioOB.Rut);
                        vend.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                    else if (UsuarioOB.Tipo == "3")
                    {
                        LoginEmpleado  emp = new LoginEmpleado(UsuarioOB.Nombre, UsuarioOB.Rut);
                        emp.Show();
                        this.Hide();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto");
            }
            cnn.Close();
        }
```

pero mi problema es que no me esta tomando el tipo 3 que seria empleado, no redireccionandome a la vista que necesito, de hecho me lleva a la vista de Vendedor lo cual es incorrecto, adjuntare imagen del codigo y a la vista que quiero llegar:

[image: vision del codigo y los forms por visual]

Me podrian ayudar a conseguir loguear con 3 perfiles distintos, la verdad me esta enredando mi propio login.

Agradecido!.

Comment: No termino de entender la logica de tu codigo, y me parece que ahi radica tu error. Vos le pedis usuario y password a la persona, y en base a eso estableces que tipo de usuario es. No agregas el tipo de usuario en la consulta, lo tomas segun quien se logueo.. se entiende? o sea, sobra el tipo de usuario en todos los selects

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que quizás estés obteniendo mal los datos. Primero coloca point breakers en cada if (tanto del validador como de las consultas) para que veas en cual se ha quedado y puedas revisar el valor interno de las variables en tiempo de ejecución.
Eso te dará una mejor idea de lo que está pasando.